# Windows 7 64-bit some panes display raw html

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, services

Display panes of some applications, for example the `Extended` tab in `services.msc`, display raw HTML instead of the list of Windows 7 (64 bit) services.

I checked the security tab settings of Internet Explorer and no site has been listed in 'Sites' option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this issue.

It is `IE8` related issue as per this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/document-explorer-fails-to-display-content/5f06ba79-c47a-41c0-8cd4-a33edea44282).

I tried the below registry entries modification solution from the above link.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm]
"Content Type"="text/html"
"Perceived Type"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html]
"Content Type"="text/html"
"Perceived Type"="text"
```

Now every window with html content (services.msc, Java Applet, Windows Help files) displays correctly.